# Are there still any free website-to-sms services?

Tags: sms

Back in the 90s I remember there were online e-mail services that allows you to send e.g. 10 free SMS messages to cell phones per month.

**Does anyone know if services like this still exist? Preferably to cell phones in Germany?**

On our current cell phone plan, we are paying an amazing 29 cents per SMS and I'm looking for a free way to get around this, e.g. from a PC or if I get a 10 Euro a month flat rate on my cell phone, then just send SMS messages via that service and side-step the expensive SMS rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this article](http://www.ehow.com/how_4448927_send-email-cell-phone.html) on eHow and [this one](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/email-to-sms/) on makeuseof.

Comment: Yep, pretty much all the cell providers allow (short) e-mail delivery to cell phones.  Generally, the proviers' web site will have instructions for converting a cell number into their particular SMS gateway.  E.g. 6045551212@txt.bell.ca (or something along those lines)  And the "general" services simply do a prefix lookup for you to determine the recipient's cell provider.

Answer (score -1):

You can find links to free web-sms services on [planet-ali.de](http://www.planet-ali.de/). There are more than 100 free sites mostly of German origin, and a few premium sites.